# Django Model Forms ( Template Doesn't Exist)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm working on Django model forms. I have created `forms.py` and added the following:

```
from django import forms 

from .models import Product

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Product 
        fields = [
            'title',
            'description',
            'price'
        ]
```

And I have rendered this out in `my views.py` as it follows:

```
def product_create_view(request):
form = ProductForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()

context = {
    'form': form 

}
return render(request, "products/product_create.html", context)
```

and I have added `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from pages.views import home_view , contact_view, about_view, social_view
from products.views import product_detail_view, product_create_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('contact/', contact_view),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('about/', about_view),
    path('create/', product_create_view),
    path('product/', product_detail_view),
    path('social/', social_view),

]
```

I have migrated everything and saved all files, but when I want to go to my create URL, I get this error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /create/
products/product_create.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/create/
Django Version: 3.2.4
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
products/product_create.html
Exception Location: C:\Users\Invoker\dev\trydjango\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Invoker\dev\trydjango\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Invoker\\dev\\trydjango\\src\\sadra',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\Invoker\\dev\\trydjango\\env',
 'C:\\Users\\Invoker\\dev\\trydjango\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 23 Jun 2021 08:20:29 +0000
```

I have created a template as well:
{% extends 'base.html' %}

```
{% block content %}
<form>
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type='submit' value='Save' />    
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Templates in `settings.py` would be like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I have my templates in a folder called templates in the root directory. In there I have another folder called products which includes `detail.html` and `product_create.html`
What should I do?

Comment: Can you add your `TEMPLATES` setting from `settings.py` and also show the directory structure where you're storing your templates.

Comment: It looks like your code is looking for the template `products/product_create.html` which does not exit. From the rest of your code, the template name should be `product/product_create.html` or `product/product_create_view.html`.

I'm assuming you wrote the wrong name somewhere, a quick ctrl+F should fix it

Comment: Just added it in the question itself. @michjnich

Comment: @AchilleHuet I have searched for typos but I haven't found anything. I have added the template in the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unclear as to your dir structure as you say "another directory", not a sub directory.

Good practice in Django is to nest dirs under a templates dir using the appname, so in our case

```
project/templates/products/product_create.html
```

Should do the trick.

You can have the `templates` folder in the project root, or you can have it in an app dir for dev (since you have set `APP_DIRS` to `True`), but you need to keep the same nesting structure.

As it stands, your project is simply not finding the correct template. Your view has the right path, but the template is in the wrong place.

Comment: Yea sorry about that, I'm a bit new. But it did the trick! 
dev\src\templates\
I had a sub directory called `product` in my `templates` directory which was located in the project root, and I was trying to call my template from a sub directory named `products`! 
Thanks a lot mate.